Getting "Uncaught (In promise) TypeError" when porting my Manifest v2 Chromium/Chrome Extension to Manifest v3
I am currently in the process of porting my manifest v2 Chrome/Chromium extension to manifest v3 and while I got the structure changed to support manifest v3, I keep getting this error when modifying my codebase. It is an extension called “PopupSound” that plays certain sounds when a browser navigation event is triggered. This is the error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: self.AudioContext is not a constructor. sw.js:5 (anonymous function)
Here is my code.
sw.js (Service Worker)
let audioContext;

// Initialize AudioContext and AudioWorklet
async function initAudio() {
  audioContext = new self.AudioContext();
  await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('audio-processor.js');
}

// Call this when the service worker installs
initAudio();

function playSound(filename) {
  if (!audioContext) {
    initAudio().then(() => playSound(filename));
    return;
  }

  fetch(filename)
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(arrayBuffer => audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
    .then(audioBuffer => {
      const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audioBuffer;

      const workletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'audio-processor');
      source.connect(workletNode).connect(audioContext.destination);

      source.start();
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error playing sound:', error));
}

function onNav({ frameId }) {
  if (frameId > 0) return;
  playSound("click.ogg");
}

chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget.addListener(onNav);
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(onNav);
chrome.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated.addListener(onNav);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onNav);

chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(delta => {
  if (delta.state && delta.state.current === "complete") {
    playSound("DownloadComplete.ogg");
  }
  if (delta.error && delta.error.current) {
    playSound("DownloadFailed.ogg");
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, { mutedInfo }) => {
  if (mutedInfo && mutedInfo.reason === "user") {
    playSound("Unlock.ogg");
  }
});


audio-processor.js
class AudioProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        // Your audio processing logic here
        // For now, we'll just pass the audio through
        const input = inputs[0];
        const output = outputs[0];
        for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
            output[channel].set(input[channel]);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor('audio-processor', AudioProcessor);



manifest.json Manifest
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
  "author": "Michaael G.",
  "version": "3.0",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "offline_enabled": true,

  "icons": {
    "32": "icon_32.png",
    "96": "icon_96.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "service_worker": "sw.js"
  },

  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "audio-processor.js",
        "click.ogg",
        "DownloadComplete.ogg",
        "DownloadFailed.ogg",
        "Unlock.ogg"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation", 
    "downloads",
    "tabs"
  ]
}

I need some help and guidance when resolving this issue. Thank you.

Service worker doesn't have DOM and other stuff that's exposed on window. Use the offscreen document.
